# How to use System IO in powershell to get the folder name without qualifiers

Tags: powershell, system-information

My purpose is to recurse through folders and rename picture files by the Date Taken - Folder Name.

The code works if I run it in the directory with the photos in it by using:

```
[string]$newDirectory = (Split-Path $Path -Leaf)
```

In the example below, how would I get only "Windows." Any other solutions would be helpful. Thank-you.

`Get-Item:
BaseName          : explorer
Mode              : -a---
Name              : explorer.exe
Length            : 2871808
DirectoryName     : C:\Windows
Directory         : C:\Windows
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Extension         : .exe
CreationTime      : 27.04.2011 17:02:33
CreationTimeUtc   : 27.04.2011 15:02:33
LastAccessTime    : 27.04.2011 17:02:33
LastAccessTimeUtc : 27.04.2011 15:02:33
LastWriteTime     : 25.02.2011 07:19:30
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 25.02.2011 06:19:30
Attributes        : Archive`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with PowerShell commands - no need to drop down to .NET:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {Join-Path $_.Directory "$($_.Directory.Name) - $($_.CreationTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd-HH-mm-ss'))$($_.extension)"} -WhatIf
```

Adjust the date/time format string `'yyyyMMdd-HH-mm-ss'` to your liking but avoid using `:` in the time part of the name.

Comment: Try the updated version - although since we are filtering on *.jpg you could just hard-code it to `.jpg`.  :-)

Comment: This works for modifying file names to creation time, however these are photos that need to be renamed to Date Taken.

Comment: For that you will need to read the EXIF data from the file. See this blog post for details - https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2005/12/10/msh-get-extended-properties-of-a-file/

Comment: OK I have two working scripts now, one where I can get the date taken, but not recurse through the folders, and one where I can recurse through the folders but not with Date Taken. I will take some time to try to put these together and post my solution.